# loading in variable states with ui-router in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a scenario where one of two default states (let's call them `foo` and `bar`) are displayed after login, depending on a user's permissions. I have a function that runs on `$stateChangeStart` that uses the user's permissions to redirect them to the correct screen.

`foo` permissions -> `mybrokenapp.com/foo/dashboard`
    `bar` permissions -> `mybrokenapp.com/bar/dashboard`

This works perfectly when the user enters via the login page. But if a user is signed in (cookie is set) and just visits the root URL (`mybrokenapp.com`) the redirection doesn't work any more.

I have debugged this to the point where I'm 99% certain the error is caused by the `currentRole` not being set when `$stateChangeStart`runs.

The routing code:

```
$stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                templateUrl: '/path/app.html',
                url : '',
                resolve: {
                    authenticated: ['authService',        function(authService){
                        return authService.authenticationStatus(true);
                    }]
                }

            })

            .state('app.foo', {
                abstract: true,
                template: '<ui-view/>',
                url: "/foo"
            })

            .state('app.foo.dashboard', {
                templateUrl: '/path/dashboard.foo.html',
                url: "/dashboard",
                controller: 'DashFoo',
                controllerAs: 'dashFoo'

            })
            .state('app.bar', {
                abstract: true,
                template: '<ui-view/>',
                url: "/bar"
            })

            .state('app.bar.dashboard', {
                templateUrl: '/path/dashboard.bar.html',
                url: "/dashboard",
                controller: 'DashBar',
                controllerAs: 'dashBar'

            })

            .state('login', {
                templateUrl: '/path/login.html',
                url: "/login",
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            })
```

The function that redirects to the correct URL based on permissions:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, authService, userService){
        authService.initialize('/api', true);

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
            if (toState.name === 'app') {
                if (userService.getUserRoles().currentRole == 'foo') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $state.go('app.foo.dashboard');
                }
                if (userService.getUserRoles().currentRole == 'bar') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $state.go('app.bar.dashboard');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue, or an alternative route design that still provides the same functionality would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem myself. Found this interesting discussion in the [ui-router github pages](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1165#issuecomment-53826639).

Problem solved by:

> initializing the state definitions with resolve: {} gives access to the actual resolve object that is used internally by ui-router, and allows to add resolves within $stateChangeStart

The code:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, authService, userService, $timeout){
    authService.initialize('/api', true);

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
        if (toState.name === 'app') {
            toState.resolve.x = function () {
                    $timeout(function(){ userService.setUserRoles(authService.user); }, 30).then(function(){

                        if (userService.getUserRoles().currentRole == 'foo') {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $state.go('app.foo.dashboard');
                        }
                        if (userService.getUserRoles().currentRole == 'bar') {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $state.go('app.bar.dashboard');
                        }
                    });
                };
        }
    });
});
```

The 30 milisecond timeout is needed to give the `authService` time to load. While this is in no way ideal, it works.

Any improvements to the aforementioned code are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer I have given in this question. It provides alternative and arguably better design
[Angular Authentication and Access control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646967/angular-authentication-and-access-control/34647081#34647081)

In the answer u can easily extend `boolean authenticate` parameter according to your needs. And authenticating service is invoked only at $stateChange event.